# Problema com componente chamado expendable no ionic 3

Tags: ionic, mobile, ionic3

Pessoal eu realmente preciso da ajuda de vocês.
De acordo com este tutorial [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/) Eu preciso de um componente customizado que me exibe o seguinte erro:

> "Can't bind to 'expandHeight' since it isn't a known property of 'expandable'."

quando eu rodo meu app.

No meu caso "home.html" é "taxa-incendio.html". Aqui está:

```
<ion-list>
  <button detail-none (click)="expandItem(item)" ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="assets/imgs/bolacha.png">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>My Neighbor Totoro</h2>
    <p>Hayao Miyazaki • 1988</p>
    **<expandable** [expandHeight]="itemExpandHeight" [expanded]="item.expanded">
        Hello people
    **</expandable>**
    <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

Meu taxa-incendio.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the TaxaIncendioPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-taxa-incendio',
  templateUrl: 'taxa-incendio.html',
})
export class TaxaIncendioPage {

  items: any = [];
  itemExpandHeight: number = 100;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.items = [
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false},
      {expanded: false}
    ];

  }

  expandItem(item){

    this.items.map((listItem) => {

        if(item == listItem){
            listItem.expanded = !listItem.expanded;
        } else {
            listItem.expanded = false;
        }

        return listItem;

    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TaxaIncendioPage');
  }

  exibir(item)
  { 
    item.styleClass = (Number(item.styleClass) == 1)?0:1;
  }

}
```

Meu taxa-incendio.scss:

```
    .ios, .md{
    page-taxa-incendio {
        button{
            align-items: baseline;
        }
    }
}
```

OBS.: Circundei o erro com ** **.

Meu expendable.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the ExpendableComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
 * Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expendable',
  templateUrl: 'expendable.html'
})
export class ExpendableComponent {

  text: string;

  @ViewChild('expandWrapper', {read: ElementRef}) expandWrapper;
  @Input('expanded') expanded;
  @Input('expandHeight') expandHeight;

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {
    console.log('Hello ExpendableComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.expandWrapper.nativeElement, 'height', this.expandHeight + 'px');   
  }

}
```

Meu expandable.html:

```
<!-- Generated template for the ExpendableComponent component -->
<div #expandWrapper class='expand-wrapper' [class.collapsed]="!expanded">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Meu expandable.scss:

```
expandable {

    .expand-wrapper {
        transition: 0.2s linear;
    }  

    .collapsed {
        height: 0 !important;
    }

}
```

[Error screen html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD6Fw.gif)

[Error screen app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOQ4O.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `home.html` você chamou pelo seletor exp**a**ndable, porem no seu `expendable.ts` vc declarou o seletor como exp**e**ndable.

Troque para

```
<expendable [expandHeight]="itemExpandHeight" [expanded]="item.expanded">
        Hello people
</expendable>
```

Comment: O mesmo erro persiste. O VSCode ainda o deixa vermelho, como se não o reconhecesse como tag

Comment: vc compilou também pra ver se o erro persiste em tempo de execução?

Comment: Sim, fiz esse teste e o mesmo erro persiste

Comment: tente definir um tipo para @Input('expanded') expanded; e  @Input('expandHeight') expandHeight;

Comment: Já os declarei separadamente lá no arquivo expendable.ts

Comment: Sim, eu falo pra definir um tipo number, any, string...

Comment: Não funcionou. O erro persiste

Comment: poderia colocar seu codigo no stackblitz?

Comment: Nunca utilizei essa ferramenta, mas pelo que entendi eu farei o upload somente da pasta src, certo? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-38qk93

Comment: sim, você também pode subir somente os componentes necessarios e lembrar de importar os componentes no app.module.ts

Comment: Eu adaptei la o seu codigo, funcionou.

Comment: voce adicionou o ExpendableComponent no seu declarations e entrycomponents no app.module.ts?

Comment: de uma olhada. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-b4wmbg

Comment: O ExpendableComponent serve para fazer um menu tipo accordion. O que me enviou o menu não consegue ter esse poder de se retrair e expandir. É exatamente o que acontece quando eu comento a tag <expendable>. Consegue ver?

Comment: Eu não cheguei a incluir os arquivos CSS no stackblitz. Mas o erro que você citou na pergunta aparentemente foi solucionado

Comment: De fato, foi sim. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda e por dispor de seu tempo para fazê-lo.

Comment: Que bom que o erro foi solucionado. Eu gostaria de poder dedicar um pouco mais do tempo para te ajudar com o accordion list, porém agora não consigo. 
Eu não cheguei a incluir o arquivo.scss no stackblitz, pode ser que com eles surja efeito. Caso não conseguir, abra um novo tópico e outros integrantes podem te ajudar com essa questão.